# Why is it that triggering a function from within a view updates the @State variable, but triggering that same function from another view does not?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

As I understand it has something to do with the fact that @State variables cannot be updated from outside a view. But I'm triggering a function within that same view, just from another view.

In my head this should work, but keen to understand why it doesn't and best way to update `myValue` from `View2.swift`

**View1.swift**

```
struct View1: View{
...

@State var myValue:Double


func myFunc(){

//Chang value of myValue
}


var body: some View{

Button{

myFunc() //clicking this updates myValue

}

...
```

**View2.swift**

```
...

Button{

View1().myFunc() //doesn't update value even though runs same function?

}

...
```

Comment: You are creating a new *instance* of the view `View1()` and calling the function on that. This is not the same instance of the view that you are seeing. You probably need a model object with an observable property that you can share between the two views.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I’ll look into models. To help my understanding, in what scenario might one want to create a new instance of a view?

Comment: Since SwiftUI views are structs, and therefore immutable, new instances are created all the time. Whenever your state property changes, SwiftUI creates a new view instance to show the updated value.  However, you would never create a new view instance outside of the view hierarchy. Ie when you say `HStack { View1() }` you are creating a new instance of the view in the view hierarchy and this is completely normal. Creating a new instance in a button action closure is pointless; the view isn't shown and will be discarded as soon as the closure exits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using `ObservableObjects`.

Comment: That's ok for model data but for view data I recommend sticking with `@State` and learning about `@Binding`, these give object-like semantics to structs.

Comment: I was really struggling to get @Binding working with TabView.